# Populate Material Design Lite Data-Table After Page Load

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, material-design-lite

I have an app using the MDL data-table sample from http://www.getmdl.io/components/index.html#tables-section However, the checkbox / selection fails to work when rows are added to the table by AngularJs data-binding (with ng-repeat) after the page finishes loading and data arrives.

Is there some MDL JS call I can make to re-initialize the table at such point or is there a better way at loading dynamic data into MDL data-tables ?/

Answer (score 2):

Currently there is no way. Data tables are very much for static content pages when using the provided JS. We are looking into methods to help with this as a part of [issue 984](https://github.com/google/material-design-lite/issues/984) for the next minor release.

Answer (score 2):

A workaround is to create a table dynamically with MDL classes and the row in question, run upgradeComponent() on it to attach the behavior and then move the row to the table where you want it to appear.

It's not pretty but gets the job done.